# How to make CodeDom generated class implement a self-referencing generic interface

Tags: .net, generics, interface, code-generation, codedom

I am generating [value objects](http://thatextramile.be/blog/2007/07/implementing-a-value-object/) and I want to switch my approach from templates to [CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) approach.

I want my types to implement one or two self-referencing generic interfaces (namely `IEquatable<MyValueObject>` and `IComparable<MyValueObject>`).

I have been able to get the desired result by doing string manipulation and calling the equivalent of `CodeTypeDeclaration.Members.Add("IEquatable<MyValueObject")`, but I would rather use the object model if this is possible.  Is there a better way or are strings going to be my best bet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
var type = new CodeTypeDeclaration("MyValueObject");
var iequatable = new CodeTypeReference(
    "IEquatable", new CodeTypeReference(type.Name));
type.BaseTypes.Add(iequatable);
```